# Return records that has one matching value in two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL table that I am trying to retrieve details from based on whether a boolean value is true.

Dummy data

```
Name    |  Score  | Deleted  | annonomous  | showuser | ID
Jane    |   5     | 0        | 1           | 0        | 7896
John    |   1     | 1        | 1           | 0        | 7896
John    |   6     | 0        | 0           | 0        | 7896
John    |   9     | 0        | 0           | 1        | 7896
```

I want to get back the records for a specific user that has an annonomous=1 OR showuser=1. NOTE these two columns can never have the same value of true together(like a toggle)

This is what I tried

```
select *
from table
where name='John' and Deleted=0 and ID=7896 and annonomous=1 OR showuser=1
```

But the above query is returning the user that I deleted

This is the output I get

```
Name    |  Score  | Deleted  | annonomous  | showuser | ID  
John    |   1     | 1        | 1           | 0        | 7896  
John    |   9     | 0        | 0           | 1        | 7896
```

But the output I wanted is

```
Name    |  Score  | Deleted  | annonomous  | showuser | ID  
John    |   9     | 0        | 0           | 1        | 7896
```

Comment: It's always the "OR" condition. The operator precedence there doesn't work how you think it should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost a typo, but you need parentheses in your `WHERE` clause:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE name = 'John' AND Deleted = 0 ID = 7896 AND (annonomous = 1 OR showuser = 1);
```

Because the `AND` operator has *greater* precedence than `OR`, your current query is being evaluated as this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE (name = 'John' AND Deleted = 0 ID = 7896 AND annonomous = 1) OR showuser = 1;
```

This version will unconditionally return any record having `showuser = 1`, regardless of who the user may be.

Comment: urg THANK YOU! the ( ) worked. i didnt even realise